# jQuery works in all browser but not in Safari - jQuery-Snowfall

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I used snowfall.jquery.min.js
[JQuery-Snowfall](https://github.com/loktar00/JQuery-Snowfall) github

It work on all browser except Safari

It show snows or images if I use images, but no movement.

Here is my code:

```
<body class="darkBg">
<div>Some text here</div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src='../dist/snowfall.jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script>     
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).snowfall({image :"images/flake.png", minSize: 10, maxSize:32});
        });
     </script>
</body>
```

### Update

Safari highlight this as an error

```
snowTimeout = requestAnimationFrame(function(){snow()});
snowfall.jquery.js:305ReferenceError: Can't find variable: requestAnimationFrame /* ERROR HERE*/
```